# How can I list the contents of the res folder in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I list the contents of the res folder in Blackberry?
For example, if res folder has four files, I want to get the names of those files in a
String array.

Comment: res folder of bb application itself?

Answer (score 1):

I would love to be wrong on this, but I'm not sure that you can do that.  I've tried something similar before, and never found a solution.

I've thought about trying to get a reference to *one* known file in my `res\` folder, or perhaps the top-level `res` directory itself.  From there, I would enumerate the contents of the directory tree.

The problem is that doing

```java
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/img/icon.png");
```

will give you an `InputStream`, which does not give you access to filesystem information (it's just a stream, which is an abstraction).

And, if you try to get a file connection

```java
FileConnection conn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("local:///img/icon.png");
```

you'll be told that the Connector class doesn't support the `local:///` protocol (I've also tried with the `cod:///` URL scheme, with no luck).

### Workaround

The only thing I suggest is that since your resource folders are read-only folders, you should be able to list out their contents at **build time**, and not have to do it inside your app **at run time**.

I don't know which build system you're using (e.g. Eclipse plugin, bb-ant-tools, JDE, etc.) but you could certainly write a desktop Java application to parse through your project's `res/` folder and write the contents to an **xml** file, that would also be placed in your `res/` folder.

Then, at run time, you could read the directory listing from the xml file.

Like I said, I'd love to know if there's a way to do this in the app, but if there's not, a pre-build script of some sort should work, too.